# Undefine all shared variables on the current node

Tags: undefined, shared, dolphindb

I have defined multiple shared tables in the current node. Are there any ways or built-in functions to undefine them at one time?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following user-defined function to see if this script can meet your requirements:

```
def existsShareVariable(varName){
     return objs(true).name.find(varName)>=0
}

def ClearAllSharedTables(){
    sharedTables = exec name from objs(true) where form="TABLE", shared=true
    for(sharedTable in sharedTables){
        print("Undef Shared Table: " + sharedTable)
        try{
            undef(sharedTable, SHARED)
        }
        catch(ex){
            print(ex)
        }
    }
    print("All shared table have been cleared !")
}
```